# Building a React/Spring Boot/MongoDB Application

Tags: html, mongodb, reactjs, spring-boot, build

I have created a React application using create-react-app. I now want to send the application to a friend so that they can use it. However, I do not want to have the hassle of all of the files, dependencies etc. Is there a way I can 'build' the application into one executable that can be run on any computer? I have no need for the application to run online, localhost is fine. I should also mention that I have a Java Spring Boot backend and a MongoDB database that are both used by the application.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to integrate with Spring Boot backend , all you need is to put the final build files in the build folder of Reactjs application into the static folder of Spring Boot project.